# White screen in google map on Android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a problem in showing google map.

In an android studio emulator I see the google map, but in the mobile app I see this:

[image]

White screen without positions in galaxy S2 and S4, so it's not the mobile.

I set the api key from google.

It's my manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.matchrace.matchrace" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.matchrace.matchrace.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.matchrace.matchrace.AdminActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.matchrace.matchrace.LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- API Key using my PC -->
        <!-- <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAbk57eU-y_eB3ywDZanb5pAh-qOEGQB0o" /> -->

        <!-- API Key using my Laptop -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyANCANO4oFrUWMtzPHSVA-e7ely8mXCRqo" />

        <activity android:name="com.matchrace.matchrace.MenuActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I set focus like this:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(32.056286, 34.824598);
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, C.ZOOM_LEVEL);
googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: Sounds like map key problem. Check if it corresponds to the certificate you use to sign the app.

Answer (score 0):

When you sign api,you get new certificate.

Save this sertificate and you have to put this md5 key to android manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where the emulator works fine, but on a real device, a Samsung tablet, I was getting a white map.

Finally, I found the reason: the WiFi connection was accidentally lost.

If you see the white map, then the first thing you should check is your WiFi connection.